# Chess books about how to deal with time troubles

Tags: books, time-management

Do any of you know if there is any book that is written about the theme "How to deal with time troubles"? It does not need to be only about time management, but at least if it has something on that topic it would be great to have the title of it. If there are any examples from real games it would be excellent.

Comment: Time trouble is a symptom, not a problem. Look at basic books by Silman (for example) that show how to 1. analyze methodically and 2. understand what should be analyzed. As you improve these skills you'll be able to move quicker and thus avoid time trouble.

Comment: @Tony Ennis: Tell that to Grischuk … ;-)

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of books that tackle the problem of time trouble at least somewhat. I would recommend [The Seven Deadly Chess Sins](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1901983366) by Jonathan Rowson. It's not solely about time trouble but touches upon time trouble often enough to be definitely useful in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

Books no.

This is a matter of proper practice along with general knowledge from books and experience from playing at slower rates gradually increasing faster as you improve.

Playing blitz will definitely harm your ability.  You need to play 'fast' but train yourself to take some time to pick a move.   Ten seconds must wait and then play is good.  You need to get in the habit of being able to move quickly but not instantly and to not waste time on moves so that you get into time trouble.